# Javafx in webpage?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So I have recently started using javafx, and have always built applications into a jar. However it's said it can be use to develop Rich Internet Applications. Ibhabr only figured out how to make it use web start. I would like to actually have my fx application running embedded in a webpage. Is this possible? If so how can I do this? I have seen the documentation page but do not fully understand it. Thanks!

Edit: just to be clear I don't want it to be a downloadable thing, it should actually show up in the browser like a JavaScript  game or an old applet, or a flash program

Comment: I think you are referring to applets. Those have been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: You can theoretically do Java Web Start, but that requires the client to have a JRE installed and won't work on mobile. Not the approach I'd usually recommend.

Comment: Yes. I do not mean clients. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_overview.htm shows that it can. That other post doesn't answer my question I want to know how to actually do it